# Isomorphic import of CommonJS modules

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, es6-modules

I've written a small library that's meant to run both in the browser and on the server. The library in turn uses npm libraries published as CommonJS modules (e.g. `lodash.isequal`).

I'd like to compile the library two different ways:

1. Using `tsc`, generating `commonjs` modules for use on the server
2. Through webpack, using the `awesome-typescript-loader`, generating `es6` modules for webpack to bundle

Per the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require), the correct way of importing CommonJS libraries which override `module.exports` is as follows:

```
import isEqual = require('lodash.isequal');
```

However for the second compilation case, typescript complains that

> error TS1202: Import assignment cannot be used when targeting ECMAScript modules. Consider using 'import * as ns from "mod"', 'import {a} from "mod"', 'import d from "mod"', or another module format instead.

I've managed to get code generation to work properly by importing it as:

```
import * as isEqual from 'lodash.isequal';
```

but that requires disabling typechecks, since otherwise typescript complains with errors like the following:

> error TS2497: Module '"/home/user/ts-mod-test/node_modules/@types/lodash.isequal/index"' resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since TypeScript 2.7, this issue can be resolved by using synthetic default imports. Using the [`esModuleInterop`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/01/31/announcing-typescript-2-7/#easier-ecmascript-module-interoperability) flag, `isEqual` (and similar modules) can be imported like in babel and webpack:

```
import isEqual from 'lodash.isequal';
```

For webpack with the `module` option set to `es6`, the import will be left as-is, and webpack itself will handle the synthetic default. For node, with `module` set to `CommonJS`, the corresponding emit will be `const lodash_isequal_1 = __importDefault(require("lodash.isequal"));`, where the `__importDefault` handles the non-es module case like Babel